# D3DCompileFromFile unresolved external when linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, unresolved-external

During the linking process, Visual Studio tells me that D3DCompileFromFile is an unresolved external symbol.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DCompileFromFile@36
```

My program compiles fine, but fails when it's linking.
I've currently got my (Project properties->Configuration properties->Linker->General->) additional library directories set to: $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86)

Please could someone let me know what I'm missing.

Also, do you need the DirectX SDK? **I've got it**, but I've read things about Windows 8 pretty much coming with it.

Edit: Also just noticed I get it for D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain too.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to link against `D3DCompiler.lib` (and `d3d11.lib`). This library is part of what was known as the DirectX SDK, which is now integrated in the Windows SDK.

Comment: Directx sdk was deprecate for years now, the directx library and the compiler is in the windows kit 8.0 since Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I've tried adding the (windows 8.1 kit) directory that contains D3DCompiler.lib to the linker additional library directories, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Hsenfow is the linking problem fixed?

Comment: No, I've still got the problem.

Comment: @Hsenfow You changed the linker library path _and_ you added this library to the list of libraries to link to your project, right?

Comment: @Hsenfow Check Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies in your project settings.

Comment: Ok, I've just added "d3d11.lib" and "d3dcompiler.lib" using the #pragma comment() thing, and it now works. Thank you.

Comment: you might also need d3dx11.lib as another note if it fails building with both d3dcompiler.lib and d3d11.lib